# How to call comparator function for sort?

Tags: c++, class, sorting

I want to use "myfun" comparator function for sorting inside the class. Is there any easy way to do so?

```
class Solution{
    public:
     //COMPATATOR  FUNCTION
      bool myfun(pair <string,string>a, pair <string,string>b){
        if(a.second==b.second){
            return a.first>a.first;
        }
        else{
            return a.second<b.second;
        }
    };

 // THE FUNCTION WHERE I WANT TO USE
    vector<string> winner(string arr[],int n)
    {
        unordered_map <string,int> dic;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            dic[arr[i]]+=1;
        }
        vector <vector<string>> li;
        for (auto name:dic){
            li.push_back({name.first,to_string(name.second)});
        }
        sort(li.begin(),li.end(),myfun);
        return li[0];
    }
};
```

Currently it's showing the following error:

```
prog.cpp: In member function std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > Solution::winner(std::__cxx11::string*, int):
prog.cpp:34:39: error: invalid use of non-static member function
         sort(li.begin(),li.end(),myfun);
```

Comment: Make `myfun` static.

Comment: it is also going to need to takes vectors of strings not pairs.

Comment: You could also explore Lambda Expressions. [Easier reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-160) and [more formal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Or also overload `operator()` as it is commonly done.

Answer (score 0):

Make the comparison function static and decide whether you want a pair of strings or vector of strings as the items you are sorting: (Pair version below; I also made the other function static so i could call it without an instance of it and made the comparator take const references.)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

class Solution {
public:

    static bool myfun(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& a, const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& b) {
        if (a.second == b.second) {
            return a.first > a.first;
        }  else {
            return a.second < b.second;
        }
    };

    static std::pair<std::string, std::string> winner(std::string arr[], int n)
    {
        std::unordered_map <std::string, int> dic;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dic[arr[i]] += 1;
        }
        std::vector <std::pair<std::string, std::string>> li;
        for (auto name : dic) {
            li.push_back({ name.first, std::to_string(name.second) });
        }
        std::sort(li.begin(), li.end(), myfun);
        return li[0];
    }
};

int main() {

    std::string ary[5] = { "bbb","ccc","bbb", "aaa", "ccc"};
    auto result = Solution::winner(ary, 5);
}
```

But really if you just want to return the first element there is no need to sort the list which is `O(n log n)` you find the first element given the comparator in `O(n)`.